# RocketMQ V5.x Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled

Tags: java, rocketmq

When I follow the [Quick Start](https://rocketmq.apache.org/zh/docs/quickStart/01quickstart).

The server has been tested on port 8081, and gRPC has been used, and the service is up and running, but when I use Java's SDK to send/consume messages, the following error is reported

```java
public static void sendMessage(String topic, String message) {
        try {
            ClientServiceProvider provider = ClientServiceProvider.loadService();
            ClientConfiguration configuration = ClientConfiguration.newBuilder()
                    .setEndpoints("ip:8081")
                    .build();
            Producer producer = provider.newProducerBuilder()
                    .setClientConfiguration(configuration)
                    .setTopics(topic)
                    .build();
            String tag = "messageTag";
            Message msg = provider.newMessageBuilder()
                    .setTopic(topic)
                    .setTag(tag)
                    .setBody(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .build();
            SendReceipt send = producer.send(msg);
            log.info("Send message successfully, messageId={}", send.getMessageId());
            producer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

then

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the service ProducerImpl-0 [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.checkCurrentState(AbstractService.java:381)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.awaitRunning(AbstractService.java:305)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService.awaitRunning(AbstractIdleService.java:165)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.java.impl.producer.ProducerBuilderImpl.build(ProducerBuilderImpl.java:93)
    at com.xmzn.common.mq.producer.SyncProducer.sendMessage(SyncProducer.java:30)
    at mq.RocketMQTest.testSendMessage(RocketMQTest.java:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.cancellationExceptionWithCause(AbstractFuture.java:1543)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:586)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:567)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:91)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.java.impl.ClientImpl.startUp(ClientImpl.java:188)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.client.java.impl.producer.ProducerImpl.startUp(ProducerImpl.java:114)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
    at org.apache.rocketmq.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables.lambda$threadRenaming$3(Callables.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

I can't find any solution online including their official community and their official documentation is very poorly written, can anyone help me!

Answer (score 0):

I met same the problem, but you can try startup rocketmq by three steps instead '--enable proxy'

```
nohup sh mqnamesrv &
nohup sh mqbroker -n 127.0.0.1:9876 autoCreateTopicEnable=true &
nohup sh mqproxy -n 127.0.0.1:9876 &
```